# how to return an array in AJAX call in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that has a select option , So I am trying to update the form/table with some content from database when I select a type in the select option ,

SO for that I did an ajax call something like this.

```
$("#selectPlantilla").on("change",function(){
        var descripcion = $(this).val();
        //alert(descripcion);

         var url="http://index.php";
            var posting = $.post(url, {
            im_descripcion: descripcion,
            }).done(function (data) {
               alert(data);
            });

    });
```

And then I validated the call in php on the same inde.php page like this

```
if(isset($_POST['im_descripcion']))
{
   $db =  new dataBase();
  $result = $db->execute("SELECT * FROM `tableNmae` WHERE `descripcion` = '".trim($_POST['im_descripcion'])."'");

  $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 print_r($result);  
}
```

The problem I am facing is in the alert window it return the whole page instead of just the `$result` that I have printed , So can any one help me out how I can channelize it properly , I have use the values from the array `$result` to update in the form using JQuery .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is in ur index.php ?

Comment: @Glizzweb it a long file how can I send it to you ? . Posting here will make the question very messy

Comment: ya your'e right so its returns the whole file..for example u create the another file like `test.php` where u can put the `if(isset($_POST['im_descripcion']))
{
   $db =  new dataBase();
  $result = $db->execute("SELECT * FROM `tableNmae` WHERE `descripcion` = '".trim($_POST['im_descripcion'])."'");

  $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 print_r($result);  
}` it will return ur result alone.i hope u understand

Comment: @Glizzweb so there is no way I can do this on the same page ? , Yes I understand that , Till now I have been doing like that only , I mean  apage that has only php functions no html tag etc

Comment: @Glizzweb got it working I validated the page :P

Comment: ya thats simple you can write the condition with return value from ajax !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For returning PHP array data in Ajax, JSON will make your life the simplest.

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo(json_encode($result));
```

This will return the array in a format that is easily usable by JavaScript.  Try this to see its content:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

With JSON, you should be able to fetch data or iterate through it in JavaScript

Comment: I know about json , But the problem here is something else , The returned value in not only the array but also the html tag etc everything , That I don't want

Comment: @Vikram Don't display any of the HTML when you're responding to an AJAX call.

Comment: Loop through the array `$result` and escape HTML tags using the `htmlspecialchars` function should do the trick.  Do this before encoding it as JSON.

Comment: @Manmaru um I just validated the complete page somethign like this `if(isset($_POST['im_descripcion'])){ return Json} else { print the rest of the page}` is this the right method . ?

Comment: If you have already validated the entire page, you can return JSON as you are doing above.  Also, if your code does nothing after echoing the JSON, using an `exit(0);` isn't a bad idea to ensure nothing else is output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.dropdown_class').on('change', function() {
         var m_val = this.value;
         var datastring = "im_descripcion="+m_val;
               $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "lunchbox_planner.php",
                      data: datastring,
                      cache: false,
                      success: function(result) {
                         var v = $.parseJSON(result);
                         var l = v.length;
                             for(var i=0;i<l;i++){

                                var sh_d = "<div class='coco3'>"+v[i]+"</div>";
                                $('.mon_tea').append(sh_d);
                             }
                      }
                });
     });
});
</script>
<div class="mon_tea">
```

**In PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['im_descripcion'])) {
   $db =  new dataBase();
  $result = $db->execute("SELECT * FROM `tableNmae` WHERE `descripcion` = '".trim($_POST['im_descripcion'])."'");

  while($row_sh = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $all_incr[] = $row_sh['col_name'];
  }
  echo json_encode($all_incr);
}
?>
```